# Unable to Install Maven plugin in Eclipse inside VMWare

Tags: linux, eclipse, maven, vmware

I am trying to install maven plugin n eclipse helios. I am doing this setup inside  VMWare  Linux setup.
 I am trying to install the software by providing this url.. 
http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e

The eclipse progress bar shows "Fetching Maven Children ( 0%) ".

It doesn't go any further than that..
I tried the same by installing eclipse on the windows environment and it worked fine.

Any suggestions on what could be wrong with my eclipse and VMWare linux setup.
The network connections are fine,I am able to connect to the internet using the firefox browser in my VMWare linux setup. I have applied the same proxy setting to eclipse network settings .

Thanks
Yogi

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set the proxy settings for Maven separately from Eclipse. Have a look here http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Using+Maven+in+a+corporate+environment